# Tableau calculated field not reading the formula

Tags: tableau-api

I'm currently doing out a formula

```
IF CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"SIT") and CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"SBM")
THEN "SIT AND SBM"

END
```

However, it is not reading out anything. But if I change the "AND" to "OR", it'll read something. Or if I change to

```
IF CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"SIT") and CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"SIT")
THEN "SIT AND SBM"

END
```

It'll read out something too. Thanks for reading!

Comment: If my below answer worked for you could you please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I can see is that you are saying for the contains to match lower(school) and yet your condition for the contains "SIT" | "SBM" is in uppercase. You should be able to get the result you want by changing your condition to lowercase as follows

```
IF CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"sit") and CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"sbm")
THEN "SIT AND SBM"
END
```

Alternatively, since you are receiving records when you look for sit and sit then I would suggest that you have no occurrences in your data where school contains both "sit" and "sbm". If what you are trying to achieve is returning any results that contain "sit" or "sbm" then you should change your statement to an **OR** statement as follows:

```
IF CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"sit") **or** CONTAINS(LOWER([School]),"sbm")
THEN "SIT AND SBM"
END
```

Comment: making it lowercase or removing the lower keyword doesn't work either

Comment: Interesting. Then my question is since as you mentioned in your question that if you change it to the second formula where you are looking for sit twice it reads something out I would suspect there are no occurrences where the school field contains both sit and Sbm. Do you need to change it to an or statement ?